# Как реализовать скроллинг?

Tags: вёрстка

Как можно реализовать вертикальный скроллинг такой же, как на [этом сайте](http://chulakov.com/work/tanuki-app)?
Какой тут плагин или библиотека используется?

Comment: Судя по названию классов у скролла это из "JQuery ui"

Comment: Глючный скроллинг. Так лучше не делать.

Comment: Копай в сторону "постраничного скролла" )))